# Replace an Underscore with a blank space

Tags: php, str-replace

I am trying to remove a underscore and replace it with a blank space using str_replace. This is being used in a word press template that is pulling a meta key value which it is doing but still has the underscores in it. Any help would be great as I have tried many thing on this. The code I am using is below.

```
<?php
    $key="property_type";
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true );
    $key = str_replace('_', ' ', $key);
?>
```

Comment: You're doing the replace after you display the value. You should do it **before**.

Comment: do you need to retrieve the meta key and its value and display them both ?? because in case you need to do this you have to send the $key as it is without any alteration then you can whatever you want with the result

Comment: I need the value returned from the key. so on a one of the property_type is commercial_properties_for_sale I need it so that is is echoing commercial properties for sale. I tried the code that was put in one of the answers and it is giving me nothing now.  <?php
   $key="property_type";
         $key = str_replace('_', ' ', $key);
         echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true );
   ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you're doing the `str_replace` after you do an `echo` so you won't see the changes. If you want to see the changes, you have to do the `str_replace` **before** doing an `echo`.

```
$key="property_type";
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true ); // get the post meta with the original key
$key = str_replace('_', ' ', $key);         // change the key and replace the underscore
echo $key;                                  // will output "property type"
```

#### UPDATED ANSWER

I was browsing the [WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) and got an idea of what is happening. Please do this instead:

```
$key="property_type";
echo str_replace('_', ' ', get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true )); // get the post meta with the original key but output the result with the value's underscores replaced.
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick response. I just tried using the below code but not it is not returning anything. Any idea of why that is  <?php
   $key="property_type";
         $key = str_replace('_', ' ', $key);
         echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true );
   ?>

Comment: @Sdesign What's your purpose for changing the `key` in the first place? You changed `property_type` to `property type` so when it tries to get the post meta it can't find it.

Comment: What I am trying to do is retrieve the property_type key value which one of them would be commercial_properties_for_sale then all I want to do is remove the underscores from this so that it would look like commercial properties for sale Thanks for the help

Comment: @Sdesign please do `var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true ));` and update your question with what it shows you.

Comment: @uon-pgregorio Thanks for the update I just tried this and now I am getting text to post but it is showing as commercial_properties_for_saleproperty type  . All I want it to show is commercial properties for sale

Comment: @Sdesign I think I understand what you're doing now. I have an **updated answer**. Please try that instead.

Comment: @uon-pgregorio awesome that did the trick. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The order should be:

```
   $key="property_type";
   $key = str_replace('_', ' ', $key);
   echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

@uom-pgregorio provided a great solution that worked for this Thanks.

```
<?php$key="property_type"; echo str_replace('_', ' ', get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true )); // get the post meta with the original key but output the result with the value's underscores replaced.?>
```